# How to loop through a list of variadic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

When I tried to iterate over variadic arguments via the following function

I don't understand '{(Print(Param),0)... } 'where 0 is used

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename T>
void Print(T& arg)
{
    cout << arg << endl;

}

template<typename ...ParamTypes>
void Func(ParamTypes &...Param)
{
    int arr[] = { (Print(Param),0)... }; 

}
int main()
{
    int num = 10;

    Func(num,num,num);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error when I don't add 0

Answer (score 3):

This a C++14 workaround for C++17 fold expressions where you can just write:

```
template<typename ...ParamTypes>
void Func(ParamTypes &...Param)
{
    (Print(Param),... ); 
}
```

`Print(Param),0` calls `Print`, throws away the result (if any) and evaluates to 0.

```
int arr[] = { (Print(Param),0)... };
```

Creates an array of bunch of zeros, but for C++14 this was one of the few places where variadic parameter packs could be expanded.

Comment: In the fold expression, you can wrap `Print(Param)` in `void(...)` to guard against users overloading `,`, if you want some extra robustness.

Answer (score 1):

As `Print` if a (template) function returning `void`, some hack is needed to manipulate it in an expression. Here:

```
int arr[] = { (Print(Param),0)... };
```

the comma operator (`,`) is used to make sure the side-effect of `Print` is manifested and yet something is returned: the zero `int`. Indeed, you cannot construct an array of `void`s.

As a reminder, the comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand, discards its result, and finally returns its right-hand operand.

It is in my humble opinion a bad hack. A more clear/explicit could be constructed:

```
struct side_effect_t
{
    side_effect_t(...) {}
};

template<typename T>
side_effect_t Print(T& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
    return {};
}

template<typename ...ParamTypes>
void Func(ParamTypes &...Param)
{
    side_effect_t{ Print(Param)... };
}
```

[demo on godbold](https://godbolt.org/z/7G7s8bz4f)

Comment: Your snippet ICEs GCC, huh.

Comment: Yeah, any internal compiler error is always a bug.

Comment: Reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111592

Comment: `side_effect_t` can easily be misused, i.e. `side_effect_t( Print(Param)... )`, and order is no longer guaranteed...